# Xamarin.forms iOS Black Screen after launching (Xamarin Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an App that's in development for quite a while now and I wanted to "port" it to iOS. When I start it, the splash screen appears and it works fine. After that splash screen it turns into a black screen, but it doesn't crash. If I create a New Application and try to run it it works perfectly. I don't use any storyboards and I'm trying to deploy to a iPhone SE. It currently has iOS 15.3 on it. What could cause this?

EDIT:
Here is the Code of the first page that the App opens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Easy_Learn.Pages.Shellpage"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Easy_Learn.Pages"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Easy_Learn"
            xmlns:viewtemplates="clr-namespace:Easy_Learn.ViewTemplates"
            xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            windows:Application.ImageDirectory="Assets"
            FlyoutHeaderTemplate="{DataTemplate viewtemplates:FlyoutHeader}"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
            Shell.TabBarForegroundColor="{StaticResource backGroundColor}"
            Shell.BackgroundColor="{StaticResource backGroundColor}"
            Shell.TitleColor="{StaticResource textColor}"
            Shell.ForegroundColor="{StaticResource textColor}">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Title="Lernen" Icon="LightBulb.png"/>
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:AllVocabs}" Title="Alle Vokabeln" Icon="Book.png"/>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:deklkonj}" Title="Deklinationen" Icon="table.png"/>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:Konjugationen}" Title="Konjugationen" Icon="table.png"/>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:adjectives}" Title="Adjektive" Icon="table.png"/>
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:profile}" Title="Profil" Icon="account.png"/>
    </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>
```

Comment: Is it a Xamarin.Forms app? Can you share the `FinishedLaunching` method of AppDelegate.cs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/443210/running-xamarin-forms-ios-gave-me-a-black-screen.html) I found that there were a few lines in the info.plist file that cause this issue. You just need to remove these lines from your info.plist and it works fine.

```
 <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
 <dict>
     <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

Comment: It is already done :)

Comment: Trying to figure out how this configuration got in my info.plist to begin with is half my battle, but my app is back up and running with this removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I have an App that's in development for quite a while now and I wanted to "port" it to iOS.

Do you want to port your app to  `Xamarin.Forms` or `Xamarin.iOS`?

The code in `FinishedLaunching` is totally different with the two ways .

If `Xamarin.Forms`

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

If `Xamarin.iOS`

```
//AppDelegate (< iOS13)
[Export ("application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:")]
public bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{          
   Window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
   Window.RootViewController = new UIViewController();
   Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();   // important 

   return true;
}
```

```
//SceneDelegate (>= iOS13)
[Export ("scene:willConnectToSession:options:")]
public void WillConnect (UIScene scene, UISceneSession session, UISceneConnectionOptions connectionOptions)
{
    Window = new UIWindow(scene as UIWindowScene);
    Window.RootViewController = new UIViewController();
    Window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();   //important
}
```

Comment: Its Xamarin.forms

Comment: Did you set `MainPage` In `App.cs` in Forms project ?

Comment: No I set a ShellPage

Comment: Could you attach the xaml code of AppShell ?

Comment: Of the ShellPage?

Comment: AppShell.xaml .

Comment: I attached it to my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241673/discussion-between-colex-msft-and-daskeksschwert3).